# Skip header of CSV file while reading in core Java with below approach

Tags: java

I want to skip the header from this csv file with the below reading mode 
        approach.
        Restricting to this mode because I am using Collections.sort which uses List as an argument.
        **Scenario :** I  am holding around 20 columns and I need to sort on the 3rd fields, then need to take the average based on 18th col for each key(3rd field). In output only 4 columns is required.

```
    ------------ skip -------
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\shekhar\\Desktop\\Lab\\DumpData.csv"); 
    //Declare file
    List<String>  lines = 
    Files.readAllLines(file.toPath(),StandardCharsets.UTF_8);//Reading file     
    Collections.sort(lines,new EmpIdComparator1()); // Sorting on 3rd field using comparator
    Map<String,List<String>> employeeById = new HashMap<>();  // Map used to decrease the column 
    ------------ skip ----------------------------------
```

**Input Data is given below in comma separated value format:**

```
    Employee Name,Employee ID,Working Hours,Date,<more columns >
    ===========================================
    Sam,002,6.5,1 Nov
    Sam,002,8,2 Nov
```

Comment: When using a scanner you can just use `.skip("\n")` to skip a line

Comment: @Lino : I am NOT using scanner class otherwise we can call readLine() once outside the loop to avoid header .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sublist does what you want, I think.

```
Collections.sort(lines.sublist(1, lines.size()),new EmpIdComparator1());
```

It only sorts the part, or view, of the list that you are passing into the method.

Comment: lines.subList(1, lines.size()) ---> fulfilled the requirement

Answer (score 0):

why not just before your collections.sort create a new List array by looping through the original but ignore the 1st lines using a variable if(lineno > 2){.....add code for list array}, and the do your sort on this new array rather than the original.

Comment: I want to skip creating another List.

Answer (score 0):

i would say use a comparator based on say your employee id then, so the sort only occurs on values over employee id 000.